# Dúvida sobre o store do Redux-React

Tags: javascript, react, redux

Tenho três reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import formularios from './formReducer';
import userLogin from './userReducer';
import errorReducer from './errorReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    formReducer: formularios,
    userReducer: userLogin,
    errorReducer: errorReducer
});
```

**Problema**

Eles funcionam corretamente, porém se dou um refresh na página, ele volta o estado da store para o estado inicial, sendo assim eu perco os dados do usuário, funcionaria assim mesmo? Como eu guardaria os dados do usuário logado, eu consegui com o localStorage e o sessionStorage, mas seria a melhor pratica?

**Obs:** É minha primeira vez aqui, se falta alguma informação, favor me informar, estou aprendendo a utilizar a ferramenta.

Comment: Sim, esse é o comportamento esperado. Quanto a "como armazenar", depende do caso. Pode ser local storage, e também existem pacotes que você pode usar como o [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) ou [redux-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-storage). Recomendo dar uma olhada para ver se faz sentido no seu caso

Comment: Valeu @RafaelTavares, li sobre o redux-persist, vai atender  a minha necessidade, resposta simples e objetiva, obrigado.